# What will be the total number of coins left then?

Tags: logic

I have:
Mr.  Smith has a bag A. Bag A has *n* numbers of bag B. Each bag B has *n* numbers of bag C. Each bag C has *n* number of one rupee coins in it.  If one bag B is removed from bag A, then the total number of coins in bag A is?
( Answer = n²(n-1) )

I cannot proceed with the method, I just don't know where and how and why to start with!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need any special tool for this. :) $ n $ - number of coins in each bag, you have three levels of bags, so you have $ n * n * n $ coins, then if you remove one bag B from A you have $ n * (n-1) * n = n^2 * (n-1) $